# How to float dynamically generated content to the right in bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `for` loop that is dynamically generating two fields(label and text box). I want the second field to be on right most corner. How should I style it?
This is the `for` loop I am using:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
            <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label">
                TextBox  
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @{
                    @Html.TextBox("TextBox")
                }
            </div>
    }
</div>
```

This is my current output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add **pull-right** class like this so it will align right

```
<div class="form-group">
    @for(int i=0;i<data.Count;i++)
    {
            <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label">
                TextBox  
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">
                @{
                    @Html.TextBox("TextBox")
                }
            </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: but this will shift the entire div to right. I just want the second element to be on the right.. I have updated my code

Comment: Check Updated Answer ,You need to apply pull-right to <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @for(int i=0;i<data.Count;i++)
    {
       <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin:0px;">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
              <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label">
                 TextBox  
              </label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                  @{
                      @Html.TextBox("TextBox")
                   }
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-6">
               <div class="pull-right">
                   <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label">
                      TextBox  
                   </label>
                   <div class="col-sm-2">
                       @{
                           @Html.TextBox("TextBox")
                        }
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used float option to align the specific component to right

```css
.right-div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group">
  @for(int i=0;i
  <2;i++) { <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label">
    TextBox
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2 right-div">
      @{ @Html.TextBox("TextBox") }
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `pull-right` class (it is replaced by `float-right` in bootstrap 4). But note that it will use `float: right` css and the `float` may have some issues in some conditions!

Other option is to use `text-right` as it use `text-align` css and this could be better in some cases.

```
<div class="form-group">
@for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
        <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label">
            TextBox  
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right"> <!-- or pull-right or float-right /-->
            @{
                @Html.TextBox("TextBox")
            }
        </div>
}
</div>
```